# Imagenes dentro de un linearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy haciendo un ajedrez, y el tablero lo hemos hecho con un montón de *linearlayout* dentro de *tableLow* y *tableLayout*.

El código es el siguiente:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.125">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/a8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.125"
            android:background="@color/negro"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/b8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.125"
            android:background="@color/blanco"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/c8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.125"
            android:background="@color/negro"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/d8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.125"
            android:background="@color/blanco"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/e8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.125"
            android:background="@color/negro"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/f8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.125"
            android:background="@color/blanco"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/g8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.125"
            android:background="@color/negro"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/h8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.125"
            android:background="@color/blanco"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>
```

Y el resultado de la vista de ese código es el siguiente:

[image: Imagen tablero formado por el código anterior]

Me gustaría saber como puedo poner la imagen del peón dentro del tablero sin que se pierda la forma del tablero, ya que como lo tengo actualmente, si pongo la imagen en un cuadrado, el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: Imagen del tablero sin forma con el peón dentro]

He intentado buscar una solución por internet, pero no he encontrado nada de ayuda. Espero que me puedan ayudar, estaría muy agradecido.

**EDITO:**

He realizado los cambios sugeridos, y el código se me ha quedado tal que así:

```
 <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.125">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/a8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.125"
                android:background="@color/negro"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/b8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.125"
                android:background="@color/blanco"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/c8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.125"
                android:background="@color/negro"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/d8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.125"
                android:background="@color/blanco"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/e8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.125"
                android:background="@color/negro"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/f8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.125"
                android:background="@color/blanco"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/g8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.125"
                android:background="@color/negro"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/h8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.125"
                android:background="@color/blanco"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>
```

Pero no sale nada en la parte de diseño.

[image: Diseño sin nada]

Answer (score 0):

El efecto que se esta produciendo se debe a que estas usando mal el peso de los linear layouts.

**Porque pasa:**

En cada LinearLayout estas poniendole ancho y alto `match_parent` y al mismo tiempo le pusiste un peso de 0.125. Me parece importante aclarar que esto sera interpretado como si tuviese puesto `wrap_content` y el peso. Por que? no hay por que.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.125"
        android:background="@color/negro"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

El problema entonces es que primero se aplica el ancho y alto dado por el `match_parten` (que en este caso funciona como `wrap_content`). Esto nos da como resultado todas las casillas vacias (alto=0, ancho=0) excepto aquella que tiene una pieza puesta, donde el alto y ancho seran el de la pieza. Posteriormente se aplica la distribucion del espacio vacio de forma proporcional segun indiquen los pesos. Como todas las piezas tienen el mismo peso todas reciben un tamaño igual de ancho y alto **adicional** al tamaño que ya tenian. Dando como resultado casillas mas grandes cuando tengan una pieza y mas chicas cuando esten vacias.

**Como solucionarlo:**

La solucion es tan sencilla como fixear el tamaño de ancho y alto de cada casilla en 0dp. De esta forma todas las casillas estaran en 0 de alto y ancho antes de que se distribuya, el espacio sobrante por el peso. Y como todas tienen el mismo peso quedaran todas del mismo tamaño, sin importar que tengan una pieza o no.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.125"
        android:background="@color/negro"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

**Conclucion:**

La mayoria de las veces quee uses pesos (weight) para distribuir espacios de forma proporcional, usalo ponienedole 0dp al ancho o alto segun corresponda. En algunos casos tambien puede ser conveniente ponerle wrap_content. Pero nunca tendra sentido que sea `match_parent` porque le estarias diciendo que ocupe todo el espacio del padre, pero al mismo tiempo solo un porcentaje de este(por eso se interpreta como `wrap_content`).

Comment: He realizado los cambios que me has sugerido, pero creo que estoy haciendo algo mal, he cambiado todos los `match_parent` por `0dp`, primero lo había cambiado solo en los `LinearLayout`, pero en la vista de diseño, no se mostraba nada, y he probado a poner también en `0dp` los `TableLayout` y `TableRow` y sigue sin salir nada en la parte de diseño. He actualizado la pregunta para que se pueda observar de manera correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Ademas de lo que comenta Erick Silva que es correcto, anque a mi me gusta colocar el layout_weight de esta forma....

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@color/negro"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Para que se distribuyan equitativamente, pero esto es un opnioón personal

Otra cosa que te podria dar error, o problemas  es el tamaño de la imagen que hace de ficha, si esa imagen fuese un imageView, deberias asignarle las propiedades de esta forma:

```
<ImageView
        ..............
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ............>
```

de esta forma te aseguras que la imagen se ajusta al tamaño del contenedor

Comment: Lo he realizado del modo en que me indicas tu, y el problema es que cuando meto la imagen, se sigue distorsionando, es decir, no se adapta del todo al tamaño...